# Ensuring the completion of Data task when the application is in background mode

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

**My Understanding of NSURLBackgroundSession :**

I know that with background session, I can initiate upload or download task and be sure that it completes the execution, even if user puts the app to background. When I create a upload or download task with background session, I am aware that a separate process takes care of the upload/download task.

But the issue with background session is, it is not designed to work with data task. Which logically makes sense as data tasks are intended to be short. On top of that, even though upload task works with background session but it can work only when the data source is file. Upload tasks with using NSData/Data as their data source will not work as well.

**My Problem:**

Keeping all these things in mind, here is my scenario :

I am using background fetch mode as one of the background mode capability in my app. When I get the background fetch trigger, I try to read the data from Health kit (Assuming the Health kit is accessible and user's device is not locked). Once I collect the data from Health Kit I need to send it to server in certain format.

Now here is the pain, Background fetch when triggered gives a very finite time to application to process (Some websites say 30 Secs, I dont rely on them though), reading the data from health kit consumes major of the time chunk allocated as a result by the time I make a web service call or when am waiting for web response, app suspends and I mostly wont receive server response.

**Here are the solutions I tried :**

1 . I know that using a background expiration handler will give me a additional processing time in background. I register a background expiration handler as soon as the background fetch triggers which is now working fine.

2. Creating a upload task to upload the data to server. I'll write the collected health kit data to a file in tmp folder and provide the link to the upload task to read from file. Which will make sure that data is transferred for sure.

**My Question:**

I think both of them have shortcomings.

***Problem with approach 1:*** Though expiration handler provides me a additional process time, what if my network call takes longer! Its working now because the data being transferred is small and network is pretty fast enough hence network call finishes before expiration handler expires. I dont think its a reliable model.

***Problem with approach 2:*** Creating a upload task just to make sure that data gets through and reaches server, doesn't sound like a great solution. Moreover writing a local file and updating it with data and then asking server guys to read from file rather than a plain JSON just to over come the shortcoming of iOS platform, doesn't make much sense either.

Please suggest what would be the proper approach to ensure the data task finishes its execution even if user puts the app to background.

Comment: Have you found any better solution?

Comment: @hassan-shahbazi : Nope, I happened to meet a Apple Developer and explained him the issue am facing because of restrictions on backgroundSession and he suggested to store data in file and use upload task :( quite disappointed but then ended up doing the same